# Deserializing class with new class names not matching properties

Tags: php

We have serialized classes stored in our database that we are trying to deserialize with new psr 4 class names. When we run the deserialize function the class is not created properly.

The old and new classes are the same the only thing that has really changed is that the names are different from psr 0 class names to psr 4 classes. When we deserialize we are making sure to use class_alias to point the old classes stored in the serialized code to the new classes. We are not getting any errors when we deserialize but the class properties are not setup properly.

For example we are working with the serialized class `Company_Shipping`. We alias that class before to `Company\Shipping`, but when we dump the object we get the properties

> private '_method' => null
>
> private '_method' (Company_Shipping) => string 'ground' (length=6)

We should be just getting

> private '_method' => string 'ground' (length=6)

So one, is there a way to access the second private property with the old class name in brackets? If I could do that I might be able to transfer the properties in the `__wake` method, but I can't figure out how to access them. However, if someone knows how to fix this deserialization that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great learning opportunity about why `private` is overkill. If the properties were merely `protected` you could have declared:

```
class Company_Shipping extends Company\Shipping {}
```

and unserialized with no problem.

At this point I would say that your best option is to leave a copy of the legacy `Company_Shipping` object code in your application, write some code to convert from `Company_Shipping` to `Company\Shipping`, [which again will be more difficult than needs be because `private`] and then either explicitly re-encode all of your stored objects to the new format or plug in various shims to detect and convert them on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that all your private properties are prefixed with the full qualified classname - and if you use an alias, this couldn't be resolved.

You could solve this problem using multiple options - but most of wont work with your existing data.

1. Option(only one, which works with your existing data): Update the serialized string. If you don't store complex data, this could be done with `preg_replace_callback` and this regex `\bs:([0-9]+):"([^"]+)"`. It would be then task of the replace callback, to update the length (first matching group) and the classname + field (second matching group).
2. Option: Make all `private` field `public` or `protected`. Doing this wouldn't cause any problems in the future with serializing.
3. Option: Make the class implement the `Serializable` interface. In this case, you have two method (`serialize` and `unserialize`), which do the serialization and can work with any string. In you case, you could return in the `serialize` a serialied array, containing all your fields and in the `unserialize` method, you have to reassign this values again.